# ADB: Launching VIEW intent from adb with multiple parameters in Uri

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I want to open a deep link in my app on Android devices. I followed the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html). Now, I'm launching the app from command line using the following command:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "example://?param1=1&param2=2" package.activity
```

I'm getting the output like this:

```
/system/bin/sh: package.activity not found
starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=example://?param1=1 }
```

Why I'm only getting `param1` in the Uri?

**NOTE**

When specifying `-D` option, the app hangs on waiting for debugger dialog.

Comment: well, `package.activity` doesn't exist... What is the name of your package?

Comment: It is MainActivity, but the weird thing is that it is reaching the MainActivity and printing the available parameters in the data. But the only parameter found is param1 @Dayan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by adding an escape character `\` between the parameters. I don't know exactly why, so please if anyone have an explanation please let me know.

Comment: in the meantime you know why?